# Dynamic Toggles not showing up in mask using C#

Tags: c#

I created a panel and in that panel I made a mask panel.

So Main Menu --> Selectable List --> Listed Toggles

```
[SerializeField] Transform RoomPanel;
[SerializeField] GameObject Rooms;
private GameObject roomsvar;

public void PopulateLists()
{

   for (int i = 0; i < roomNameList.Count; i++) {
        roomsvar = (GameObject)Instantiate (Rooms);
        roomsvar.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = roomNameList [i];


        roomsvar.transform.parent = RoomPanel;
        Debug.Log (roomsvar.GetComponentInChildren<Text> ().text);
}
```

The Debug.Log shows that it loads my list and in the inspector while running it creates the clone Toggles and when navigating those clones the Labels say as they should. However, the box they're supposed to load into stays blank.

In the settings panel I've done the same thing and it DOES show up. I feel like I'm missing something either in the inspector settings or maybe with layers? I'm not sure. I'm still figuring out how to manipulate dynamic gameobjects. The clones are created in a GridLayOut Group and set to list each one one on top the other.

Can someone point out what I missed to list each clone so the user can see it?!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. I was initializing the lists during the Awake function and for whatever reason it will roll through the code but will not make my toggles visible. I moved it to the Start() function and it makes my clones visible. Odd, can someone explain why?